# java JFileChooser File Size Filter

Tags: java, swing, file, jfilechooser, filefilter

I know I can make a filter by file type, but is it possible to filter by file size?

For example a JFileChooser to show only pictures within 3 MegaBytes.

Comment: Have a look at [addChoosableFileFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#addChoosableFileFilter%28javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter%29) - you can create a filter which takes a `File` as a parameter, and returns a `boolean`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer should be, what have you tried?  The long answer is yes...

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
fc.addChoosableFileFilter(new FileFilter() {

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File f) {
        String name = f.getName().toLowerCase();
        return (name.endsWith(".png") &&
                        name.endsWith(".jpg") &&
                        name.endsWith(".gif") &&
                        name.endsWith(".bmp") &&
                        f.length() < 3 * (1024 * 1024));
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return "Images < 3mb";
    }
});
```

Technically, you can filter on any property or combination of properties from `File`

Answer (score 2):

Create a sub-class of FileFilter. In the accept method, decide if the file is too large or not.

```
public boolean accept(File f) {
    if(f.length() > maxSize) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Then apply the filter to your File Chooser